# Error in one to many relation mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Two Table : `opinionPoll` and `result`.

Having `One(opinionPoll) to Many(result) relation`.

When I try to get record from other table using an Alias then got a error for mapping.
when I delete the parent child(results) are not deleted but parent deleted. I think  my problem is in mapping so the below code of my tables.

For opinionPoll:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
            @JoinColumn(name = "pid", nullable = false, updatable = true)

            private List<PollResult> pollResults = new ArrayList<PollResult>() ;
```

For result:

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name = "pid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private OpinionPoll opinionPoll;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
For OpinionPoll:

// mappedBy "opinionPoll" --> the OpinionPoll object in Result class
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="opinionPoll")
private List<PollResult> pollResults = new ArrayList<PollResult>() ;


For Result :

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pid")
private OpinionPoll opinionPoll;
```

Comment: when i try to save  child obj 
opinionPoll=opinionPollDao.getPoll(pollId);
      opinionPoll.getPollResults().add(pollResult);
      opinionPollDao.savePoll(opinionPoll);
 
i got an error org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gcm2`.`tbl_poll_result`, CONSTRAINT `FK8208399C8E2A768A` FOREIGN KEY (`poll_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_opinion_poll` (`poll_id`))

Comment: Seems that "pid" is not correct and you have to change it to : "poll_id"
 ,,, would u provide the column names in both tables please ?